# Where to put Firebase.setAndroidContext() function

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to play a bit with Firebase and Android.
I have one `RegisterActivity`, and one `MainActivity`.
My current flow is - start with `MainActivity` - check if user is registered, if not, call `RegisterActivity` - after registeration call `MainActivity`.

I'm having trouble with where to put the `Firebase.setAndroidContext()` call.
I have 2 questions:

1. Should I only call this function once in `Application` or once in each `Activty`?
2. If the answer for question 1 is only once, then where should I put it ?

Thank you all,
Giora.

Comment: why you don't wanna start register activity – check user logged – if true: start MainActivity?

Comment: According to the current documentation:
*"In the new SDK, it's no longer necessary to call Firebase.setAndroidContext() so you can remove it from your code"* https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android - in section **Setting the Android Context and enabling Offline Persistence**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To quote (step 4 of) the [Firebase quickstart documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html):

> The Firebase library must be initialized once with an Android `Context`. This must happen before any Firebase reference is created or used.

Create **`MyApplication.java`**:

```
public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //Previous versions of Firebase
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        //Newer version of Firebase
        if(!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

And update *name* parameter value in your **`AndroidManifest.xml`**:

```
<application 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyApplication">
...
</application>
```

Answer (score 3):

As seen in the [sample applications](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat) of Firebase you should place it inside your `Application`.

```
package com.firebase.androidchat;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

/**
 * @author Jenny Tong (mimming)
 * @since 12/5/14
 *
 * Initialize Firebase with the application context. This must happen before the client is used.
 */
public class ChatApplication extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/androidchat/ChatApplication.java)

---

**`Firebase.getAndroidContext()`**

After setting the Application context once you can use it where ever you need it. You can retrieve it as often as you like, everywhere. 
I would also recommend to use the `Firebase.getAndroidContext()` instead of storing it into variables to prevent MemoryLeaks

Comment: Thanks for your answer - It is also correct, but I can only mark one as an Answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @gioravered i answered first :P but no problem. Please also check their sample apps on github. they help you ;)

Comment: @gioravered in fact the other answer you marked as correct does not answer your initial question how to use `getAndroidContext()`

Comment: @mikepenz is it also not recommended that the root references to firebase should also be created only once? Or is it once per activity? How to handle that?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know FireBase but i know Android.. A `Context` is a global information about an application environment. Your `Activity` is a `Context` so i am pretty sure `Firebase.getAndroidContext()` retrieves your Application `Context` which is `getApplicationContext()`, Since that seems sensible.

> Should I only call this function once in Application or once in each Activty?

call it whenever you need a `Context` with respects to FireBase codes- but i think will suit best if you call it in your `Application` class

> If the answer for question 1 is only once, then where should I put it ?

what if its not once? where do you call it? i guess you will call it anywhere you need `Context` right? so do that irrespective of question 1's answer, but you can fall on `Class.this` , `getBaseContext()` or `View.getContext()` anytime

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant setAndroidContext() and not getAndroidContext().

Comment: well an upvote will be cherished even though i was still on point..lol right?@gioravered

Answer (score 1):

In the new SDK, it's no longer necessary to call Firebase.setAndroidContext() so you can remove it from your code.

You can read about updates and changes here:
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

Answer (score 0):

You can do both. If you set it just once then it should be here. Anywhere else and your app will crash. Debugger will say that you have not setAndroidContext():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
// The rest of your code goes here
```

If you want to use for multiple activities then create a class that has the same name as the app, make sure that the class extends Application.

```
public class NameOfApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
}
```

}

After that update the application tag in the manifest.xml file with the following:

```
android:name=".NameOfApp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` code with `mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`

And add `private DatabaseReference mRef;` before **onCreate** methode.

I hope this will work for Android Studio 3.5 version.