# Firebase Android "using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase." Error

Tags: java, android, firebase

I use firebase on android  v2.2.0
the app works fine most of the time.
but   when i leave app for a long time (let's say 2-3 hrs+) and return to app it most likely error.

and send error report to check it always  this report.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.
```

I have already set  at top of onCreate(); on every activity as installation guide from www.firebase.com

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    // other setup code
}
```

what should i fix?

Comment: posable duplicate [Where to put Firebase.setAndroidContext() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138017/where-to-put-firebase-setandroidcontext-function)

Answer (score 3):

> In the new SDK, it's no longer necessary to call Firebase.setAndroidContext() so you can remove it from your code.

Link: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#setting_the_android_context_and_enabling_offline_persistence_numbered

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the context in the application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a configuration file "ConfigApp"

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
}
```

and in AndroidManifest add

```
 <application
        android:name=".ConfigApp"
..../>
```